# A new arranging of discrete sine transform

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-transform, signal-analysis, trigonometric-sums

Let $n$ be even and  consider the discrete sine transform of type 5 which is the matrix

$$S=\left(\sin(k+1)(l+1)\frac{\pi}{n+\frac12}\right)_{k,l=0}^{n-1}$$

Let us denote by $s_{-,l}$  the $l^{\text{th}}$-column  of $S$. It can be considered as an $n$-tuple in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Q.**  I am looking for $n$-tuples $v=(v_0,\dotsc,v_{n-1})$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $v_j=\sin2(j+1)\frac{\pi}{n+\frac12}$ if $j$ is even.
2. The following  are valid concerning inner products: $$\langle v , s_{-,l} \rangle=\begin{cases}
        1 & l=0 \\
       0 & l\neq 0~,~  \text{$l$ is even.}
     \end{cases}
   $$

P.S. Let us consider only entries of $S$ which are located on the even columns and odd rows and say it $\tilde{S}$. It is a submatrix of $S$. How can we prove that $\tilde{S}$ is invertible? If we could prove this point, the above mentioned problem would be solved.

Comment: TeX notes: the `\left\{\begin{array}…\end{array}\right.` idiom is better rendered as `\begin{cases}…\end{cases}`.  Also, `\operatorname` should not be used for plain text in math mode; that's what `\text` is for. For example, when one adds sentence-ending punctuation, one gets $l \operatorname{is even.}$ `l \operatorname{is even.}` vs. $\text{$l$ is even.}$ `\text{$l$ is even.}` (which some people prefer to set as `l\text{ is even.}`).  I have edited accordingly